# cannot read property of undefined в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Например есть метод:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.panel = this.panel.bind(this)
    this.searchIconsTypes = this.searchIconsTypes.bind(this)
    this.searchIconsActive = this.searchIconsActive.bind(this)
    this.moveForward = this.moveForward.bind(this)
    this.moveQuery = this.moveQuery.bind(this)
}
 moveForward(id, type) {
        if (type < 4) {
            return (
                <Button
                        type="button"
                        rel="tooltip"
                        title={`Move to ${this.types[type + 1]}`}
                        onClick={this.moveQuery = (id, type) => {}}
                        className={`btn btn-simple btn-xs  color_${this.types[type + 1]}`}>
                    <i className="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
                </Button>
            )
        }
    }
```

Но выдаёт ошибку

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'moveForward' of undefined

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код компонента полностью. Из приведенного фрагмента не ясно где вызывается moveForward.

Comment: компонент очень большой. вывожу просто в рендере типа { this.moveForward(customer.id, customer.type) }

Comment: Есть ещё три метода, точно по такому же принципу обьявляются и используются в рендере и они роаботают

Comment: А в render вызываете `moveForward(...args)` или `this.moveForward(...args)`? :)